# Setting Lotus Notes section border using VBA

Tags: vba, lotus-notes

Friends,

I'm using VBA to create Lotus emails populated from an Excel spreadsheet, and I'm stuck on a really silly point.

When I create a new section in the note, business rules require me to give it a border. They've been doing this manually for years and are used to doing this from the Notes UI. They create a new section, then go to its properties and then change it to have a border (please see the border and style part in the properties window in this [screenshot](http://goo.gl/CiDqf)).

I can't figure out how to add this border through VBA. Any ideas? I've tried changing the TitleStyle, but that only affects things like fonts and color. I have everything else done, just stuck on the border!

Thanks!

Mike

Answer (score 2):

The NotesRichTextSection class doesn't give you any way to change the border, unfortunately.  Rich text items in Lotus Notes aren't supported very well via the API, so often you'll find a mismatch between what you can do on the client vs. what you can do in code.

There might be a workaround if you're up for trying it.  First you need to create a simple form in Notes that has a rich text field, let's call it Body, surrounded by a section.  Setup the section to appear however you want, with the border set, etc.  You'll also need another hidden text field, called Title, and you'll set the section's title to be computed based on that Title field.

Then in your VBA code you're going to create a new NotesDocument based on that form.  You'll set the Title field, and you'll add content into the Body rich-text item.  Then you'll need to call the ComputeWithForm method followed by the Save method.  Finally, you can use the RenderToRTItem method on the document to put the entire document into your original note's rich text field.  Make sense?

No guarantees that will work from VBA, but I've done similar things in the past using LotusScript and it did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You could just set the borders of the cells you are copying using the Borders() property.

**Example:**

```
Range("B2:C4").Borders.LineStyle = xlDash
Range("B2:C4").Borders(xlEdgeBottom) = RGB(255,0,0)
```

Comment: @Ken, I think you need to read my answer more carefully.  He can set the border on the Excel Range before he copies it, and it may copy with the borders (it would take testing to see if the borders import).

Comment: @Lance, excuse me if I sounded rude.  But you are missing the point of his question.  He's talking about adding a border to a section in Lotus Notes, which has nothing to do with the borders in the Excel document or range of cells.  See the screenshot he attached.  I think the question title and tags should probably not reference Excel.  This is really a Lotus Notes only question.

Comment: @Ken, I was thinking that he wanted a border for the section in Lotus Notes, and that a border for the Excel cells that were imported would do, as a substitute for the Lotus border, again, not knowing if this would actually work.  I guess we'll wait for him to explain more.

Comment: @Lance, I keep coming back to this thread, rereading my comments, and realizing I sound like a jerk.  Anyway, again, please excuse the curt replies.  I get your point and since the answer is going to involve a workaround either way, who's to say your answer won't address his issue.  I'm changing my vote! :)

Comment: Learning something new everyday!  I can't change my vote apparently.  I'm "locked in" unless you edit your answer, unfortunately.

Comment: @Ken, haha, ok, I'll edit it.  If the OP ever gets back to us, and shows me it won't work I'll just delete it though.